# Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

Let $N$ be the number of taxis arriving at an airport terminal per minute. It is observed that there are at least 2 arrivals of taxis in each minute. Based on a study performed by a traffic engineer, the probability $P(N=n)$ is proportional to the following function:
$$\displaystyle \frac{e^{-2.9} \cdot 2.9^n}{n!}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n=2,3,4,\cdots$$

What is the average number of taxis arriving at this airport terminal per minute?

My solution so far
$\sum_{2}^{\infty}k \frac{e^{-2.9} \cdot 2.9^n}{n!}$  where k is a constant

Comment: why is $k$ a constant?

Comment: Under your assumptions, that sum has to be $1$, yes?

Comment: Hint:  You can use that sum to compute $k$, the constant of proportionality.  Once you know the value of $k$ then the average is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }n\times P_n$  where $P_n=k\frac {e^{-2.9}2.9^n}{n!}$